# Xamarin - White spacing getting added when using Height="Auto" for Grid

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

The image below is created using XAML and a grid to display the images. There should be a fourth row at the bottom but it keeps adding all this extra white space at the bottom of each row. The spacing between rows is set to zero and I have no idea why this is happening.

[image]

If i change the 4 Autos to * for the rowdefinitions, it get this where the text is cut off.

[image]

A fix for either of these would be very helpful as I have spent hours try to find the right combination of Aspect for the images/VerticalOptions to make this work.

Code:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
        <Frame Margin="15,30,15,45" Padding="10,10,10,10">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0">

                <Label Text="Moby Debt Rating Scale" FontSize="20" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                <Label Text="% Reeled In Since Joining GradFin" FontSize="14" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                <BoxView HeightRequest="3" Opacity="0"/>
                <BoxView HeightRequest="0.5" Color="Black"/>
                <BoxView HeightRequest="3" Opacity="0"/>


                <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
                        <Image Source="@drawable/SeaGull.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Text="Seagull" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label Text="0% - 5%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/StarFish.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Starfish" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="6% - 10%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/LightHouse.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Lighthouse" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="11% - 15%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/JellyFish.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Jellyfish" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="16% - 20%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/ShipWheel.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Ship Wheel" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="21% - 25%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>


                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/Fish.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Minnow" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="26% - 30%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/WaterDrop.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Sea Storm" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="31% - 35%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/TackleBox.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Tackle Box" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="36% - 40%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/Bobber.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Bobber" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="41% - 45%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/Compass.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Compass" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="46% - 50%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>


                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/Crab.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Crab" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="51% - 55%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/Sailboat.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Sail Boat" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="56% - 60%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/Anchor.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Anchor" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="61% - 65%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/Octopus.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Octopus" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="66% - 70%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/FishingRod.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Fishing Rod" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="71% - 75%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>



                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/Hook.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Hook" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="76% - 80%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/Lobster.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill"  />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Lobster" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="81% - 85%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/FishingLure.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Fishing Lure" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="86% - 90%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/Fisherman.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Fisherman" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="91% - 95%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="@drawable/Whale.PNG"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Whale" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="96% - 100%" FontSize="12" TextColor="#FF2665CA"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: At first glance I'd say look at your different `VerticalOptions` of the `StackLayout`'s and try just `Fill` or `Start`.

Comment: That worked. Not sure how but setting the RowDimension to * and all the VerticalOptions to Start fixed the extra white space. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Strange but it worked for me too.